# How can I use Excel to scatterplot more than 255 X-Y pairs from .csv file?

Tags: excel, excel-charts, excel-import

My XY data is converted to a category axis when I attempt to scatterplot more than 303 pairs; bogus data generated IN Excel (such as going to cell B3 and entering B2+1, then dragging that formula down to 1,000 rows, doing same in column C) will correctly plot 1000s of pairs by selecting data through highlighting X and Y columns and picking scatterplot.  Same values brought into Excel in .csv format data does not not work that way. Why?  I'm working in Excel 2016.

Clicking on the plotted pairs and changing the "imported" .csv data as shown switch my X-axis max from ~150,000 (which is correct) to 350, the 350 being related to number of pairs (304); if I use 7,000 pairs, the X-axis goes to ~7,000.

Examples of data series info Excel displays in "url"-like window:
OK:
=SERIES('50_compare'!$C$1,'50_compare'!$B$2:$B$304,'50_compare'!$C$2:$C$304,1)
Not OK (same file, same plot, :
=SERIES('50_compare'!$C$1,'50_compare'!$B$2:$B$305,'50_compare'!$C$2:$C$305,1)

In the latter case, it apparently lumps both X and Y columns as a single series, though the code in the box (shown) looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I had one bad value ("******") in 7,500 pairs, and rather than inform me there was a bad value, Excel changed an X-Y scatter plot into a Y vs "category X" plot, limiting the data to 255 categories and plotting both X and Y as the same data series.

Comment: (not coincidentally it the bad data fell on line# 304 )